# Prove or disprove the orthogonal complement of an infinite subspace is {0}

Tags: linear-algebra

I am trying to disprove or prove this:

Let $V$ be an infinite subspace and $U$ be one of its subspaces, then $U^\perp=\{0\}$ iff $U=V$

If the space is finite-dimensional, it would only require the rank nullity theorem. But I found it very hard to work with infinite-dimensional subspace since theories like rank nullity theorem does not apply. Is there a more general rank nullity theorem in infinite-dimensional vector space or there is a counterexample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In infinite dimension that statement doesn't hold. Take, for instance, the space$$V=\{\text{sequences }(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\text{ of real numbers such that }n\gg1\implies a_n=0\}$$and$$U=\left\{(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\in V\,\middle|\,\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{a_n}n=0\right\}.$$On $V$, take the inner product$$\bigl\langle(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N},(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\bigr\rangle=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nb_n.$$Then $U^\perp=\{0\}$, but $U\varsubsetneq V$.